# How can I change this linear Java Code for a program that adds and subtracts to Object-Oriented Code

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple android app that can add and subtract numbers, but my challenge is to make sure that the program is Object-Oriented. Currently I have been told that it is linear, but I am confused as to how it has remained linear after trying many times to make it object-oriented. How can I make this object oriented programming. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class addNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    
    { // Begin main
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );  // Instantiate object input
        
        System.out.println("Enter number 1"); // Ask the user to enter number 1
        double number1 = input.nextDouble();  // Read the first number
        
        System.out.println("Enter number 2"); // Ask the user to enter number 2
        double number2 = input.nextDouble();  // Read the second number
        
        double sum=number1 + number2;  // Add the numbers
        double difference = number1 - number2; // Subtract number 2 from number1
        
        System.out.printf("\nSum = %f\n", sum); // Print the sum
        System.out.printf("Difference = %f", difference); // Print the difference.
    }

} // end main
```

Comment: You wouldn't.  There isn't enough complexity here to be worth bringing into objects.  The point of OOP is to make code easier to read and think about through encapsulation.  There's nothing to encapsulate here.

Comment: Also, just a side note-  your end main comment is on the wrong line-  the end of main is the first }.  The one you have commented is the end of the class.  Just pointing it out so you realize.

Comment: Are you expected to make a whole (simple) calculator out of this or is the sum and subtraction (and the user entering only 2 numbers) all the app needs to do? I am assuming this is an assignment, since you "have been told that it is linear". Elaborate a bit on what the challenge is, so that we can help you out. Right now we would really need to "make up the complexity" for this to use 2-3+ classes.

Comment: Yes its an assignment and he provide this linear java code and he ask to change it to OOP .

Comment: it literarlly says like this. "The Java code attached adds and subtracts two numbers using linear programming.  Please rewrite this code using OOP and provide your code.  In this way, the code will have the same functionality but it will use OOP." i am kind of confuse too because there is not a lot of complexity to just program add and sustract.

Answer (score 0):

My applications use this boilerplate to execute inside an object. If you start like this, you can add methods as you need them.

```
public class Demo
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        final Demo app = new Demo ();
        app.execute ();
    }

    private void execute ()
    {
        // Do stuff here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoever gave you this assignment is using wrong and confusing terms, because [linear programming is something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). But that's a different topic.

Even though this program is not complex, we can introduce some classes by modelling the flow of the program and/or the math operations.

Here is one idea... we could have a class called `Operands`, that has a method to read the numbers from the input while it prints instructions to the output. Then it stores these two numbers.
So something like this (I am using `static class` here instead of just `class` in case you will put this inside your `public class addNumbers`)

```
static class Operands {
    public final double first;
    public final double second;

    public Operands(double first, double second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public static Operands readFromIO(InputStream in, PrintStream out) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(in); // Instantiate object input

        out.println("Enter number 1"); // Ask the user to enter number 1
        double number1 = input.nextDouble();  // Read the first number

        out.println("Enter number 2"); // Ask the user to enter number 2
        double number2 = input.nextDouble();  // Read the second number

        return new Operands(number1, number2);
    }
}
```

Then we could have another class called `Calculator`, that has a method to set the operands `setOperands(Operands operands)` and two methods to get the results for the sum and the difference. The methods could be called `getSum` and `getDifference`.

```
static class Calculator {
    private double sum = 0;
    private double difference = 0;

    public void setOperands(Operands operands) {
        sum = operands.first + operands.second;
        difference = operands.first - operands.second;
    }

    public double getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    public double getDifference() {
        return difference;
    }
}
```

Then in the main method of the program, we just need to make an instance of the `Calculator` class and set the `Operands` on the instance. We read these operators by calling `Operands.readFromIO(...)`. Then we retrieve the sum and the difference from the calculator instance.
So the code in main looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator c = new Calculator();

    Operands operands = Operands.readFromIO(System.in, System.out);
    c.setOperands(operands);

    System.out.printf("Sum = %f\n", c.getSum()); // Print the sum
    System.out.printf("Difference = %f\n", c.getDifference()); // Print the difference.
}
```

This is just one way to do it with some objects.

Another way could be to use an interface called `Operation` that contains a `calculate(Operands operands)` method and have 2 more classes `Addition` and `Subtraction` implement the interface. Then you would use those two classes to calculate the results.